# setuid example from Wikipedia: 4700

Tags: permissions, executable, setuid

I was reading about [setuid on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). [One of the examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#4700) goes as follows:

> 4700
>
> SUID on an executable file owned by "root"
>
> A user named "tails" attempts to execute the file. The file owner is "root," and the permissions of the owner are executable—so the file is executed as root.
>
> Without SUID the user "tails" would not have been able to execute the file, as no permissions are allowed for group or others on the file. A default use of this can be seen with the `/usr/bin/passwd` binary file.

I do not understand this. How can user "tails" execute this file at all, since he is not the owner of the file, and group and other permissions are not available?

I tried to recreate this scenario, and indeed:

```
$ su -c 'install -m 4700 /dev/null suidtest'
$ ls -l suidtest
-rws------ 1 root root 0 21 dec 07:48 suidtest*
$ ./suidtest
bash: ./suidtest: Permission denied
```

I only got this working with permissions of `4755`. Also, the default use mentioned in the example on Wikipedia (the `/usr/bin/passwd`) has in fact `4755` permissions.

Is the example correct and am I missing something, or is this a mistake?

Comment: You are right and the Wikipedia article is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right and the Wikipedia article is wrong.  See the below for an example:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd 
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 30768 Feb 22  2012 /usr/bin/passwd
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/passwd /tmp/
$ cd /tmp
$ ls -l passwd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30768 Dec 21 07:43 passwd
$ sudo chmod 4700 passwd
$ ls -l passwd
-rws------ 1 root root 30768 Dec 21 07:43 passwd
$ ./passwd
bash: ./passwd: Permission denied
$ sudo chmod 4701 passwd
$ ./passwd 
Changing password for user vagrant.
Changing password for vagrant.
(current) UNIX password: 
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since the example on Wikipedia has been "peer-reviewed" (no-one adding an explantion to this example has changed it), it looked like I was missing something.

Comment: Please fix Wikipedia